# How to make Vertical Box List structure using html and css

Tags: html, css

I want to make something like this. https://www.screencast.com/t/FGZW259E9twg
Some points(I can only use one class, only "dd and dt" can be used and structure needs to be like if I add one more "dd and dt" it'll automatically take its structure like previous ones.So can't hard code in CSS.)
The HTML code i can use is only this.

```
<dl class="vertical_box_list">
            <dt>
                <select>
                    <option value="1">Option1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option2</option>
                </select>
            </dt>
            <dd><p>Land must be purchased before road excavating can start</p></dd>
            <dt>
                <select>
                    <option value="1">Option1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option2</option>
                </select>
            </dt>
            <dd><p>Road excavating must start before Asphalt can be laid</p></dd>
            <dt>
                <select>
                    <option value="1">Option1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option2</option>
                </select>
            </dt>
            <dd><p>Laying Asphalt must be complete before line painting can be completed</p></dd>
            <dt>
                <select>
                    <option value="1">Option1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option2</option>
                </select>
            </dt>
            <dd><p>Road excavating must start before Asphalt can be completed</p></dd>
        </dl>
```

CSS i tried this but only one problem that all the "dt" automatically hides except first one if i use "position:absolute."

```
.vertical_box_list dt
{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 140px;
    height: 80px;
    background: antiquewhite;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 89%;
    left: 2%;
}
.vertical_box_list dd
{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: aliceblue;
}
.vertical_box_list dt select
{
    position: relative;
    top: 35%;
    left: 20%;
}
.vertical_box_list dd p
{
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
}
```

Comment: You can use pseudo classes like `::before` `::after` `:nth-child` `:not()` to accomplish what you want. If you post some code that you have tried I can guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
dl {
  max-width:30rem;
}

dt, dd {
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}

dt {
  left:1rem;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0.125rem 1rem;
  border:1px solid white;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
  z-index:2;
}

dd {
  top:-1rem;
  display:block;
  padding:1rem;
  padding-top:2rem;
  text-align:right;
  z-index:1;
}

dt:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: rgba(236, 126, 61, 1);
}

dd:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: 1px solid rgba(236, 126, 61, 1);
  background-color: rgba(236, 126, 61, 0.25);
}

dt:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: rgba(208, 124, 96, 1);
}

dd:nth-of-type(2) {
  border: 1px solid rgba(208, 124, 96, 1);
  background-color: rgba(208, 124, 96, 0.25);
}

dt:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 217, 114, 1);
}

dd:nth-of-type(3) {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 217, 114, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 217, 114, 0.25);
}

dt:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: rgba(165, 165, 165, 1)
}

dd:nth-of-type(4) {
  border: 1px solid rgba(165, 165, 165, 1);
  background-color: rgba(165, 165, 165, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<dl class="vertical_box_list">
<dt>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
    </select>
</dt>
<dd>Land must be purchased before road excavating can start</dd>
<dt>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
    </select>
</dt>
<dd>Road excavating must start before Asphalt can be laid</dd>
<dt>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
    </select>
</dt>
<dd>Laying Asphalt must be complete before line painting can be completed</dd>
<dt>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
    </select>
</dt>
<dd>Road excavating must start before Asphalt can be completed</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: If I use (4n+1) property instead of hard code then it will automatically take the structure of next element.

Comment: Not exactly if you want 4 different colors.

Comment: After 4th list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your dts are behaving that way is because they're being positioned relative to their most immediate, non-static parent, I'm guessing it's the dl.

The html doesn't have an element for the close button in your image so that would have to be achieved by a pseudo-element. That's absolutely positioned to not interrupt the dimensions of the dt itself. (if you even need it)

Using `position: relative;` on the dt/dd, you can adjust their z-indexes and move the dt to overlap the dd. You want the  as position relative so it's laid out, occupying its original space in document flow, *relative* to where that would be (if you give it 'coordinates')

[Here's a stab at it.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZJyZd?editors=0110)